# How do I get rid of the unwanted white-space on the left and right of my slider?

Tags: html, css, bxslider

I have been trying to figure this out for a long time now, and I really could use some help. Since the bxslider is exactly what I need I just want to know how to get rid of this:

code:

CSS:
http://pastebin.com/L8Xh1ENf

Markup:
http://pastebin.com/KStgy9Dt

Any help would greatly be appreciated!

Comment: We're going to need some code if you want help?

Comment: Please paste some code.

Comment: I have used pastebin because I cannot figure out how to paste code into stack overflow.

Comment: If you could paste the relevent code into jsfiddle.net that would be much better.

Comment: Please provide a small self-contained example, which contains just enough code to demonstrate the problem, without anything extra. Post this code into the question, AND in a JSFiddle (jsfiddle.net). Doing this can be a lot of work, but it's a critical part of the process of troubleshooting your problem. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve .

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the spaces was the "margin:0px auto 60px;" this property is centering the slider in the middle, hence creating spaces to the left and right side.

In addition to that, there were many markup with margins, select all elements and use this

```
*{margin:0;padding:0;list-style:none;}
```

This will reset everything

Here's the working [**code**](http://jsfiddle.net/f7hAL/)